# how can I know if an applet is running in a browser vs. invoked from Eclipse

Tags: java, applet

As from subject. How can I determine if the applet is running in the browser? I want to have a mock data provider to do debugging without involving the browser, and neutralize all the LiveConnect calls I have if I'm not in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not [add a parameter](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Flaunchers%2Feclipse_application_launcher.htm&cp=4_3_3_0) for use in Eclipse? Read this on `init()` and if found handle appropriately.

EDIT: Update URL.

Comment: The link is no longer active.